# Google Chrome Android Tablet (Three.js is not working)

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I´m trying to display a three.js model on the Google Chrome app, but it doesen´t work. On the destop browser there is following error:

(`three.js:29522 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/bruechic/Desktop/html5_demo/ThreeJS/models/R8.mtl. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`)

So i have to open Chrome with "- chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files" to run it.

Is there a possibility to run my app in the Chrome-app on Android? With the Firefox-app it works fine on Android :-/

Sourcecode:

```
THREE.Loader.Handlers.add(/\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader());
  var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
  mtlLoader.setPath('ThreeJS/models/');
  mtlLoader.load('R8.mtl', function(materials) {

    materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.setPath('ThreeJS/models/');
    objLoader.load('R8.obj', function(object) {
```

Comment: Have you tried just running it on Android?  Put everything in relative paths and don't specify the protocol.

Comment: yes i tried it on the android-Chrome-app but only the container is displayed, no model. I´m not a expert in three.js i just copy a model loader, what do you mean with relative paths?

Comment: In your code you use relative paths so it's already doing it, assuming the files are in the right place.  Basically, have your app in a folder and the ThreeJS and models folders within that folder.  If it's not working like that then it *may* be the same issue you experience on desktop, but don't count on it.

Comment: i tried it but it doesent work already, it seems that chrome blocking all file-requests, but why is firefox fine with my code.  Btw thanks for the fast answer :-)

Comment: The error you posted, from the desktop version, is likely to be completely unrelated to the error on your Android device. How do you host the webpage (not app!) you are trying to view from Android Chrome? Do the online three.js examples work on the Tablet? Learn how to use https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ to analyse the problem.

Comment: The model is working fine with the Firefox-app on the tablet. From this I conclude thats the same problem at the chromeapp as when i use chrome destop version.